# Publish MQTT messages TO sensors (not FROM)

Tags: mqtt

**MQTT** is usually described in IoT scenarios where there are lots of publishers (e.g. field devices , sensors) and likely few subscribers (e.g. application servers).

I would like the application servers to be able to occasionally send messages to selected field devices. That would mean that application servers would be the publishers and field devices would be the subscribers.

Is MQTT designed to correctly flow info into this direction: From a few publishers to thousands of subscribers? Is the architecture and protocol designed to efficiently cope with such scenarios? If not, are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

MQTT works fine in both directions.

If the field devices can be grouped then a topic per group would work, but equally fine for each device having it's own topic to send a message to a single device.